# Mongodb like system with permissions over sections

Tags: web-apps, gui, mongodb, nosql

I would like to know if there is some sort of web app that works like PHPMyAdmin in the sense that it is basically a web interface for a database, which, in my case, is mongodb.

Unlike phpmyadmin which provides permissions for databases and tables, I need to have different permissions over different "sections" of the same record/document.

Let me give an example: Suppose I have many JSON documents like this one on a mongodb collection for registering teams in a scientific Olympiad:

```
{
    "team_id": 43749328748,
    "school_id": 88932,
    "school_name": "Hogwarts - Department of Acre",
    "participants_ids": [3243, 5453, 54354, 323],
    "final_score": 9.5
}
```

In this scenario, I need to allow teacher to edit all fields *of the teams that belong his school* but the `team_id` and the `final_score`. And, at the same time, the judges need to have write permission only to the `final_score` field.

I'm sure that there are at least a few registration systems like what I've described, however, I would like to have something more generic and adaptable to changes.